# Trouble with sending a message over a UDP Socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am currently attempting to form a program that allows two programs to communicate using one go between file, acting as a data link layer.

The problem I'm having is that even though my message seems to be sending across the network, **the message that is received has some weird garbage text after it**, and when it is then passed to the main file, the garbage text is all that is passed, and the **message disappears completely**. Any pointers in the correct direction are greatly appreciated.

Sending program

```
main(){

    dlinits("hostname", 43520);
    dlsend("hello");

}
```

Receiving program

```
#include <string.h>
char* dlrecv();

main(){
    char* test;
    dlinitr(43520);
    strcpy(test,dlrecv());

    printf("%s\n", test);



}
```

Data Link program

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFMAX 100

static int sk;
static struct sockaddr_in remote;
static struct sockaddr_in local;

dlinits(char* host, int port){//initialize sender

    struct hostent *hp;
    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    remote.sin_family = AF_INET;

    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (hp == NULL){
        printf("Can't find host name\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bcopy(hp->h_addr,&remote.sin_addr.s_addr,hp->h_length);

    remote.sin_port = ntohs(port);
}

dlinitr(int port){//initialize receiver
    int rlen = sizeof(remote);
    int len = sizeof(local);
    char buf[BUFMAX];

    sk = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    local.sin_port = htons(port);
    bind (sk, &local,sizeof(local));

    getsockname(sk,&local,&len);

}

dlsend(char* msg){//send data

    printf("%s\n", msg);
    sendto(sk,msg,sizeof(msg)+1,0,&remote,sizeof(remote));
} 

char* dlrecv(){//receive data
    char* msg[BUFMAX];

    recvfrom(sk,msg,BUFMAX,0,&remote,sizeof(remote));
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
sendto(sk,msg,sizeof(msg)+1,0,&remote,sizeof(remote));
```

Should be

```
sendto(sk,msg,strlen(msg)+1,0,&remote,sizeof(remote));
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I overlooked that. Beyond that, my second issue I managed to solve, I simply needed to malloc the char in my dlrecv function to send the correct value over to it.

Comment: Don't forget to also pay attention to the return value of `recvfrom()` to know how many bytes were actually received. You do not have to send a null terminator, the message boundary can act as the terminator instead.